# How to send Email to every host in scala play framework?

Tags: scala, email

Right now, i am able to send my email to current host where i have declared in the scala code application.conf

```
smtp.host=apps.hubino.com, smtp.port=25
```

but i am unable to send my mail to other host like gmail and yahoo. Can anyone help me how to achieve sending mails to every host in scala.

Answer (score 0):

I am sending email through google smtp server with these configuration.

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=yes
smtp.user=“********@gmail.com"
smtp.password=“**********"
```

This should work. Also if you make small changes in host and port you should be able to send email to any other smtp servers.

Which scala plugin you are using to send email? You can check [MailerPlugin](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) of Play or [Courier](https://github.com/softprops/courier) plugin. Both are very simple to use.

And first time google will block sending email through you application as it is less secured so you need to make changes in your gmail account settings to allow sending email through less secure clients. This [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) can help you do that or else if you try to send email without making these setting you will received email from google saying securing 'Blocked sign-in attempt' which will contain URL to make changes in your account setting to allow sending email through api client.